# Working the ski season in France

Tags: france, work

A friend and I will be looking to work in the French Ski fields during the coming winter.

If you have done this before: Where is the best place to start looking? Do you have any tips on best places to go, or jobs that are avaliable for travelers?

Unfortunately neither of us speak French but we are good learners.

Comment: This question is list-type of question. There is no right answer for it.

Comment: not looking for the right answer just some tips to start looking - have edited the question tho. cheers

Comment: @Peter - sorry, but SE sites are all about the "right answer". Questions requesting tips aren't a good match.

Comment: @Dori most of the related questions on the right side of the screen are non specific question asking for tips or opinions. they all recieved helpful answers. how is mine any different?

Comment: @Peter - they are looking for a "right" answer.

Comment: Not that some questions without one right answer have been allowed to thrive. Particularly the bike rental in Europe question. So the rule is not yet consistently applied.

Comment: www.natives.co.uk will give you all the info.